# Parse json response in object c from http get request

Tags: objective-c, json, cocoa, http, nsstring

i'm trying to parse the response i get from a http get request in object c, i have do this:

```
    NSString *returnValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:oRespondeData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    SBJsonParser *jParser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
    NSDictionary *JSONresponse = [jParser objectWithString:returnValue];
```

then i search for a specific key:

```
NSArray *jSon1 = [JSONresponse objectForKey:@"links"];
```

and in the array there is only one element, and if i log it i have this:

```
NSLog(@"%@",[jSon1 objectAtIndex:0]);
```

log:

```
(
"Video.720p.X264-..",
"",
"http://video/dl/Video.720p.X264-.."
)
```

how i can get the url with http? i have tried everything, i have also tried to trim the string to delete the whitespaces, but seems that it's not a nsstring because i receive

```
[__NSArrayM stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

how i can do?

Comment: What versions of iOS are you supporting?

Comment: i'm doing it in Mac OS X, not iphone...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[jSon1 objectAtIndex:0]`

is returning an array of 3 separate strings, so if yo'ure trying to get the 3rd string you could do:

`NSArray *links = [jSon1 objectAtIndex:0];`

`NSString *httpUrl = [links objectAtindex:2];`

Hopefully i understand your question correctly.